# LaTeX pdf screen not appearing and pdf file not compiling after removing /usr/local

Tags: compiling

I'm running on macOS Big Sur 11.4. Hopefully, someone can help me.

Recently, I wasn't able to compile R packages properly, so it was suggested to me to remove all file from /usr/local via

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/*
```

Now my packages compile as needed, but for some odd reason, LaTeX pdfs no longer compile.

When I navigate over to `/usr/local/bin` and look at what files are there, I see

```
R           makeinfo        texi2any
Rscript         pdftexi2dvi     texi2dvi
gfortran        pod2texi        texi2pdf
info            sqlite3_analyzer    texindex
install-info        tclsh8.6        wish8.6
```

but I'm not sure if something may have been erased.

I'm no computer wizard, so any help in fixing the issue is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

When I do a Quick Build, the pdf screen does not appear and the pdf is not generated. I just get a number of warnings pertaining to missing fonts and under/overfulls, which were not there prior to the problem occurring. The square boxes in the blue text occurred when I updated to macOS Big Sur long before the current problem happened

Should I just uninstall and reinstall LaTeX?

[image]

EDIT:

I am using TeXmaker with pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17.

Unfortunately, this is all I am able to gather because when I updated to macOS Big Sur this summer, it somehow corrupted my TeX messages (but everything else still worked up until now).

Comment: You were advised to do `rm -fr /usr/local/`? That's really bad advice.

Comment: you really should not follow an advice telling you to erase everything in a folder.

Comment: Can I restore `/usr/local`?

Comment: you can only restore it if you backed it up

Comment: but if you are generating the warnings you show in the summary image, you must have tex installed somewhere

Comment: It appears that things weren't uninstalled when I did `rm`, but I can't see why the pdf won't compile anyway.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would an uninstall/reinstall solve the problem?

Comment: the default install of upstream in usr/local, but you are presumably using a tex in /bin, but hard to say as you haven't shown any information

Comment: you haven't said what the problem is, tex seems to be installed but you have removed an unknown number of applications by deleting usr/local, and an unnamed pdfviewer in an unnamed editor isn't working, so installing tex won't help but re-installing the editor (you have not said which that is) and/or a pdf viewer may help

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17. Please see my edited post with more information.

Comment: pdftex doesn't seem to be the issue, you are using some editor (whatever editor has a "quick build" option and its pdf viewer is broken so you need to say what that is, but sorry I can't help more (I don't use a mac)

Comment: Oh Sorry. I am using TeXmaker. Does it suffice to uninstall and reinstall it, or find a new editor altogether?

Comment: In Terminal run the commands `which pdflatex` and `echo $PATH` and let us know what they return. Also that command removed dynamic libraries so you may have other applications that are going to give you problems.

Comment: @HerbSchulz `which pdflatex` returns `pdflatex not found`. `echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`

Comment: For now, I've imported my files to Overleaf, which seems to be a good temporary fix.

Comment: @compbiostats : That looks like you had MacTeX installed and it was removed by that `rm` command. You'll have to re-install MacTeX: go to [https://www.tug.org/mactex/](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) and download the `MacTeX.pkg`, Double-Click it and follow the directions to (re)install TeX Live, Ghostsceript, etc. PS: You removed a bunch of command line applications in /usr/local/bin with that `rm` command so you may have other problems.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Thanks. I've managed to do exactly this. Because I did an `rm`, would there still be issues with LaTeX, or just with other applications?

Comment: @compbiostats : possible problems with other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved.

I simply uninstalled LaTeX by moving the TeX folders in `/Applications` and `/Library` to the trash and then installed the latest version of MacTeX (my previous install was from 2017) and TeXmaker (the LaTex editor I use).

I then simply had to declare

```
\UseRawInputEncoding
```

in the preamble of my documents.

Hopefully my experience can help someone in the future (and to NOT do `rm -fr /usr/local/` (although to my knowledge, only R and LaTeX files in  `/usr/local`),